# Voltage across an unbalanced resistor bridge

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, bridge

[image]

In the above circuit R1 = R2 = R4 = 1 ohm and R3 = (11/10) ohm. I have to find the voltage V.

Initially I tried using voltage division in (2 ohm/2.1 ohm) x 10 V = 9.52 V and (2.1 ohm/2 ohm) x 10 V = 10.5 V. Subtracting them gives +1 V. Is this correct?

Next using current division first I found equivalent resistance = 1.024 ohm and current I=V/R which is 9.76 A using current division current I got 4.99 A and 4.76 A in each which gives voltage 9.99 V and 9.98 V. What is wrong here?

Options are a)1V b)-0.238 V c)+0.238V and d)+0.138 V

Comment: can you give your nodes names? It's exhausting to write about "the point where R1 and R4 meet" or something.

Comment: considering your previous question: you're familiar with (unloaded)voltage dividers, aren't you? It feels like you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: **Hint1:** Voltmeter shows the difference of voltages across R4 and R3. **Hint2:** R1-R4 and R2-R3 form dividers, and they both are across the supply.

Comment: @RohatKılıç   The voltage across R1-R4 and R2-R3 are both 10 V each. So i can use voltage division and get voltage across R1-R4 which is 5V each. And now for R2-R3 whose voltage to calculate

Comment: Yeah, simply calculate the voltages across R4 and R3 individually, by using the voltage division equation. And take the difference, by taking the the sign of the voltmeter into account.

Comment: If the supply is 10 volts, and the resistors are (nearly) equal value, the mid points of the two legs of the bridge must be near 5 volts, and certainly can't be 10.5 V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *In the above circuit R1=R2=R4=R and R3=(11/10)×R. I have to find the
> voltage V*

Regard the two sets of voltage dividers as independent and regard the voltmeter terminals as having infinite impedance: -

- At the junction of R1 and R4 is 5 volts. Do you see that?
- At the junction of R2 and R3 is 5.2381 volts. Do you see that?

The answer you are looking for is the difference of these two voltages.

---

**From comments**

> *Across R2 it is = 4.76 and across R3= 5.238 now which one to subtract
> with 5. And what if all Resistances were different then which resistor
> voltage to subtract with which one? R1 is also on positive terminal and R2 is on -ve terminal just like R3. What is the reason not to subtract their voltages instead subtracting Voltage across R4 and R3. – Adyy*

Because the circuit has a GND (or 0 volt) reference point at the base of R4 and R3. That reference point dictates how voltages on other nodes are defined. Hence we subtract the R3 voltage from the R4 voltage.

<sub>This means we use the voltage across R4 and, subtract from it the voltage across R3.</sub>

The voltage across R4 is the positive voltage (as indicated on the voltmeter terminal with the positive sign in your diagram). From that you subtract the voltage across R3 because, by inference, it is on the negative terminal of the voltmeter.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCnbsa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input resistance can be found:

$$\text{R}_\text{in}=\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)=\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag1$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

Now, the input current is given by:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_\text{in}}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag2$$

Now, the current \$\text{I}_1\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$

Now, the current \$\text{I}_2\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag4$$

So, we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{A}=\text{I}_1\cdot\text{R}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag5$$
- $$\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{I}_2\cdot\text{R}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag6$$

So, we also get:

$$\text{V}_\text{A}-\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}-\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\right\}\tag7$$

> Using your given values we get:
>
> $$\text{V}_\text{A}-\text{V}_\text{B}=10\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\text{R}}-\frac{\displaystyle\frac{11}{10}\cdot\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{11}{10}\cdot\text{R}}\right\}=$$
> $$10\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{42}\right)=-\frac{5}{21}\approx-0.238095\space\text{V}\tag8$$

Comment: idk what is wrong in  but answer is -0.238 not 10.2381 ... maybe terminals A and B are different then what asked ?

Comment: The last operation is wrong. VA is 5V, VB can't be negative to get an A-B difference of >10V.

Comment: @Adyy found the issue and fixed it.

Comment: @JanEerland I am still confused, Why R1 and R2 are in series in your circuit. Why current not Dividing in R1 and R2 instead dividing on R1 and R3.? This Va-Vb is different then what i asked yet how come its -0.238 too. Va should be between R1 and R4 and Vb between R2 and R3.

Comment: @Adyy I renamed the resistors in my circuit compared to your circuit but that does not matter of course.

Comment: Using the OP's resistor naming would make your formulae apply to the OP's problem directly, without requiring a translation step which is extra complexity, extra distraction for someone to whom the answer wasn't obvious in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the voltmeter has infinite resistance then the answer is trivial as above. If it is a traditional moving coil or moving iron voltmeter it will take at least 100uA, maybe over a milliamp and certainly cannot be neglected. You cannot use simple parallel/series resistor combinations in this case. You need to write down all the voltages and currents as a matrix and then use matrix arithmetic to find the answer. As this is cumbersome you might need to use a program such as Octave (or Matlab) to get the answer. Or you can use spice simulator to find the DC operating point.